# Error when trying to import module ballerinax/kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, microservices, ballerina

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jzhr.png)

I am unable to implement the Kubernetes module onto ballerina

here is the error message

**cannot resolve module 'ballerinax/Kubernetes(BCE2003)**
PS I am using Windows

Comment: Thank you for your question. Please include any code snippets as text, rather than images. When including images, please write an image description that is accessible to screen readers.

Comment: Problem here is, you are trying to use a Ballerina 1.2 syntax with Ballerina Swan Lake (2.x). In Swan Lake, you have to follow https://ballerina.io/learn/running-ballerina-programs-in-the-cloud/code-to-cloud/code-to-cloud-samples/ to deploy with kubernetes.